# How to save a file from wave and sounddevice?

Tags: python, wav, wave, python-sounddevice

someone made a script who is supposed to record a wave file and send it at an email address.

I want instead of send it at an email address, save the file.

Here is the code :

```
import sounddevice as sd
import wave

fs = 44100
seconds = 60
obj = wave.open('sound.wav', 'w')
obj.setnchannels(1)
obj.setsampwidth(2)
obj.setframerate(fs)
myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)
obj.writeframesraw(myrecording)
sd.wait()
```

After launching the script, I have an empty wave file.
Is there something to save the file or something like that `obj.save(r'XX')`?

Comment: You forgot to close the file(`obj.close()`)

Comment: Did you even take a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html)? It specifically recommends to use a `with` statement so that the file is automatically closed...

Comment: There is no need to cast `int(seconds * fs)` since `seconds` and `fs` are already `int` themselves. Also, post the original code (the one sending emails) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

U need to close the wave object

```
import sounddevice as sd
import wave

fs = 44100
seconds = 60
obj = wave.open('sound.wav', 'w')
obj.setnchannels(1)
obj.setsampwidth(2)
obj.setframerate(fs)
myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)
obj.writeframesraw(myrecording)
sd.wait()
obj.close()
```